# iOS-charts radar chart removing labels and filling the web with color

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-charts, radar-chart

Probably a very basic question.

I am using [iOS-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and am working with a radar chart.

I am struggling to figure out how to remove the labels from the graph and I am really struggling to FILL the web. I can change the outer lines but I want to fill the web/data in a specific colour.

any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: Can you add a link to the library you're using?

Comment: Hi,https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: I have partly answered my own question regarding filling the web with color:  chartDataSet3.fill?.color
        chartDataSet3.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        chartDataSet3.drawFilledEnabled = true

Comment: Can you provide drive or dorpbox URL of your demo code? so anyone can download and provide you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are two types of labels on a radar chart, the axis label that shows you the list of possible values on the chart from min to max and the labels that correspond to each point on your graph.

REMOVING AXIS LABELS

- Grab either the x or y axis on your radar chart view and set drawLabelsEnabled to false depending on the axis of the labels that you wish to hide

  ```
  let yAxis = radarChartView.yAxis
  let xAxis = radarChartView.xAxis

  yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
  xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
  ```

REMOVING LABELS FOR VALUE OF EACH POINT

- Go to the location that you create your RadarChartDataSet
- Before using it to create your RadarChartData, set the drawValuesEnabled property to false

  ```
  let radarChartDataSet = RadarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "label")
  radarChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
  ```

Also, here's a link to the Charts documentation page which can also be helpful (although it is not fully filled-in): http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Charts/2.0.9/index.html